# Build unqlite for Windows Phone 8.1 Store Apps (WinRT)

Tags: c++, build, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, unqlite

We are developing a C++ core for our mobile app. We would use unqlite DB. We compiled it successfully for iOS and for Android.

http://unqlite.org/downloads.html

When we try to compile it for WinRT, we receive a lot of errors. There is someone who has compiled it for WinRT?

Theoretically Windows Phone is supported (http://www.developereconomics.com/five-popular-databases-for-mobile/).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As I know, if you have some C++ Library and want to use in Windows Phone Project you need:

- Create Windows Runtime Component (C++ project)
- Include your C++ Library into Windows Runtime Component
- Establish bridge between your C++ Library and Windows Phone Project

You cannot include an usual C++ Library in Windows Phone (Store) project

Comment: I've already created my runtime component where I include all c++ libraries, but the build process of official unqlite sources fails. I'm searching if exists a visual c++ porting for Windows Runtime.